# How to make TalkBack read TextView error message automatically?

Tags: android, textview, talkback, accessibility

I'm currently making my app accessible and I'm having problem with my EditTexts:

In every EditText, the user's input is being validated at some point (e.g. after pressing a button) and if the input is invalid, I show an error using `editText.setError("message")`. The problem is that if TalkBack is on, it will not automatically focus and read the error. Also, since I can't get the error's view, I can't ask TalkBack to focus it via `sendAccessibilityEvent`.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this issue while still using `editText.setError()`.

**Edit 1** Added code for @Abhishek V solution:

```
public class BaseEditText extends EditText {

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error) {
        super.setError(error);
        announceForAccessibility(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can explicitly read out the error message through `announceForAccessibility("mesage")` function provided by `View`

```
editText.setError("message")
editText.announceForAccessibility("message");
```

Please note that this function was added in **API level 16**.

**update 1:** Set the error message to `null` when the text is changed in `EditText` to prevent reading error message again and again.

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                editText.setError(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it still have two issues: 1. Talkback doesn't focus on the error message (not a big deal) 2. When I type in the editText after showing the error one, talkback reads the error message again - after the visual error already disappeared. Any idea how to deal with those issues?

Comment: 1) Not sure how to fix that 2) When exactly are you calling announceForAccessibility? Can you post that code?

Comment: I just added the announceForAccessibility() to my custom EditText's setError (see update to question)

Comment: Yap, that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Abhisek, I am using an EditText for Zipcode purpose. after entered zipcode:4587. It reading as four thousand eight seven like that, But, I want to read as Four Five Eight Seven. any update for your code on the above? any suggestion.

Comment: @harikrishnan I guess you can programmatically append space between each characters. It should read it out as individual numbers

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried it in Textview, which is reading as expected. the same for EditText also. but, its not reading as expected. If possible , please try once for Edittext with Zip code numeric and let us know, if possible.